# Tuning an electric organ keyboard

Tags: keyboard, solid-state-devices

I have an old (1960's) [Whippany Dart](http://www.combo-organ.com/Melosonic/) combo organ. Each set of three keys has a tuning pot that raises and lowers the pitch of those three notes (turning clockwise lowers the pitch, and counterclockwise raises the pitch). I'm not sure what determines the pitch of the three distinct notes within each group.

[image: Tuning Pot]

For one particular set, turning the pot as far as it wil go counterclockwise still leave each note in the set about a half note below the desired pitch.

My question: Is there an obvious way to raise the collective pitch of one of these sets? Perhaps adding or changing one of the resistors in the group?

(I do not have a schematic.)

Comment: Just learned that these organs are also referred to as "Melosonics". Searching that term turned up [this page](http://synthrepair.blogspot.com/2011/02/melosonic-300.html) which might contain the answer. I'll follow up if I can confirm that information, but I welcome any other info in the meantime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a schematic, here's what you can try...

Judging from the picture, your organ uses RC oscillators. When the pitch is too low, you need to use smaller capacitors or smaller resistor values.

When the group of three notes is good in itself, just offset with regard to the neighboring groups, I would try to leave the capacitors untouched, and see what happens when you add resistors in parallel to the existing ones. Let's say an existing resistor has 10 kΩ. A good way to start is paralleling another resistor with 10...50 times the value of the original one, i.e. something like 220 kΩ. It is very unlikely that you break something as long as your additional resistors are > 4.7 kΩ.

Trial and error might eventually lead to success...

Don't expect an organ like this to be or remain perfectly stable and expect some dirtyness even when you try your best using the pots - but that's the cool part about old instruments anyway, isn't it?